# Why `sudo chmod –R u-w .` does not recognices -R as an option when using dot=current dir?

Tags: command-line, chmod

Typing

```
tute@my-server:/opt/npm/capa$ sudo chmod –R u-w .
chmod: invalid mode: ‘–R’
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.
```

Why when I use the current dir `'.'` `-R` does not works?

Comment: Something is wrong with your  `-R` switch, change `–R`  with  `-R`.

Comment: ufs. You are right! Thank. I'm writing a doc in word, coping and pasting the commands to the console to test.

Comment: To change that behavior, try using Courier font.

Comment: @WillemK: That shouldn't change the behaviour but make the difference between a simple dash (U+002D, hypen-minus) and an em dash (U+2013) more obvious visually.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: That was my idea too, but apparently the Courier font makes it the least visible result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears the text processor in question “helpfully” converted the simple dash (U+002D, hypen-minus) to an em dash (U+2013).

Many text processors have a few features that are nice for the type setting of natural language texts but a nuisance when writing formal language texts, vulgo “code”. If you want to type code (incl. terminal commands) into a text editor I suggest you use a *plain text* editor like [Gedit](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gedit/)<sup>1</sup>/[Pluma](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=pluma&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all)<sup>2</sup>, [Mousepad](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/leafpad/)<sup>7</sup>, [Leafpad](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/leafpad/)<sup>3</sup>, or [Kate](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/kate/)<sup>4</sup> for a graphical user interface or [Nano](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nano/)<sup>5</sup>, [Joe](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/joe/), or [Vim](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vim/)<sup>6</sup> for a terminal interface.

---

<sup>1</sup> default in Unity (Ubuntu “vanilla”) and GNOME (Ubuntu Gnome) desktops

<sup>2</sup> fork of [Gedit](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gedit/), default in MATE desktop (Ubuntu MATE)

<sup>3</sup> default in LXDE desktop (Lubuntu)

<sup>4</sup> default in KDE desktop (Kubuntu)

<sup>5</sup> default in all Ubuntu editions

<sup>6</sup> Vim “tiny” (a. k. a. `vi`) is default in Ubuntu “vanilla” Desktop and Ubuntu Server

<sup>7</sup> default in Xfce desktop (Xubuntu)